# Python AttributeError: module 'rpm' has no attribute 'TransactionSet'

Tags: python, rpm

Getting this error`Python AttributeError: module 'rpm' has no attribute 'TransactionSet'. Installed rpm module like this pip3 install rpm. Do I need to install any other modules?

Comment: are you using a script and is it callled `rpm.py` by chance ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this module, but I hope I can help.

I imagine that you have installed this module via `pip install rpm`

Pypi offical docs says:  https://pypi.org/project/rpm/

> Placeholder package to make the RPM Python API available through PyPI.
>
> Right now, this package just reserves the rpm name on PyPI to avoid the >potential for a name conflict with the python2-rpm and python3-rpm Python >bindings on RPM-based Linux distros.
>
> Unlike libsolv and libdnf (which use CMake, and are hence amenable to PyPI >compatible build automation with scikit-build), rpm itself still uses >autotools, so creating usable pip-installable Python bindings for it may be >a bit trickier than doing so for the other libraries.

So un-install this package `pip uninstall rpm` and then install it from system scope `apt-get install python3-rpm`.

Maybe you need to re-install virtualenv like `virtualenv --system-site-packages rpm` and make rpm  available to virtenv. Because `apt-get install` will enable rpm for system python, not for virtualenv